# Implement search filter with mat select multiple

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select

I'm trying to implement a search filter for a multiple mat-select but I have an issue when I'm searching and selecting.

My search function is working properly. But if I search for something, select it and then search for something else and select it, only the last selected item is kept. This is because of my search not being reset but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to clear my search input when I close the mat-select panel but it doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<mat-select formControlName="testCategories" [(ngModel)]="testCategories"
    multiple>
    <input matInput class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..."
        (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-chip-list>
            <mat-chip *ngFor="let category of testCategories" [removable]="true"
                (removed)="removeCategory(category)">
                <div class="chip-text">{{ category.name }}</div>
                <mat-icon class="icon-delete-circle-reverse" matChipRemove></mat-icon>
            </mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let category of selectedCategories">
        <mat-option [value]="category.id">
            {{ category.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

TS:

```
    onKey(value: string) {
        this.selectedCategories = this.search(value);
    }

    search(value: string) {
        this.filter = value.toLowerCase();
        return this.categories.filter(option =>
            option.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(this.filter));
    }
```

Comment: `testCategories` preserving only one latest item, You can add into array uplon every item selection. Can you share it on stackblitz?

Comment: **Remove** the `formControlName="testCategories"`. You're using template driven form, **not** reactive Forms. BTW thre're some errors in your code: your array `categories` should be an array of string if you want to use filter(option=>option.toLowerCase) or an array of object if you use category.id in the .html.

Comment: I changed the original code a bit. In my search function I use category.name.toLowerCase(). I edited the post to make it clearer

Comment: @akromx Is it solved ? I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 onKey(value: string) {
        this.selectedCategories.push(this.search(value));
    }
```

Comment: I have a property type issue. "Argument of type 'Category[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Category'."

Comment: In order we help you better, we need to know more data: How/Where you declare selectedCategories, categories, etc But, but the error message, it seems that you declare selectedCategories as Category, whereas it should be Category[]

Comment: selectedCategories and categories are both declared as Category[].
I have to push Category type and not Category[] I think.

Answer (score 0):

The `search(value: string)` method returns an array. You can try the following

```
onKey(value: string) {
    this.selectedCategories.concat(this.search(value));
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-select formControlName="testCategories" [(ngModel)]="testCategories"
multiple>
<input matInput class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search..."
    (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
<mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngFor="let category of selectedCategories" [removable]="true"
            (removed)="removeCategory(category)">
            <div class="chip-text">{{ category.name }}</div>
            <mat-icon class="icon-delete-circle-reverse" matChipRemove></mat-icon>
        </mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</mat-select-trigger>
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of selectedCategories">
    <mat-option [value]="category.id">
        {{ category.name }}
    </mat-option>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I still have the issue.

Comment: can you check what the `selectedCategories`  contains after onKey is executed

Comment: selectedCategories contains all of the categories.

Comment: You are using `testCategories` on your html. But I don't see it in the ts code.

Comment: testCategories is the array of categories that I get from API and send to.

Comment: Updated the HTML In my answer.